# more symbolic logic practice

Tags: first-order-logic

Below are some statements that I would like to know how to express symbolically:

- 1) x is a power of 3
- 2) $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a bijective function
- 3) $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is an invertible function

Here are a few clarifications:

- 1) **No** *exponentiation* or *compound* statements are allowed. That would make it too simple, as shown in the incorrect answer for *1)* given below.
- 2) f(x) is *invertible* simply means that it has an inverse.

Questions:

- 1) Does my answer to 1) work and if so, why? A brief but comprehensible explanation will suffice.
- 2) Do my answers work? And if so, can they be made more concise?

Here's what I have so far:

- 1) Note first that no power of 3 is negative. Now, we define the compound statement that $x$ is prime.
  $\exists x\in\mathbb{N} (x >1 (\exists a,b\in \mathbb{N} (x=ab) \Rightarrow (a=1\vee a=x)))$.
- Next we define the compound statement that $x$ is a factor of $y$
  $\exists y\in \mathbb{Z}, \exists x\in\mathbb{Z} (\exists z \in \mathbb{Z} (y=xz))$.
- Now, we can use these compound statements freely.
  $\exists x \in\mathbb{N} \wedge (\forall y\in\mathbb{N} (y$ is prime $\wedge y$ is a factor of x) $\Rightarrow y=3) \Leftrightarrow (\exists z\in \mathbb{N} (x = yz) \Rightarrow y =3z)$.
- 2) $\forall y \in \mathbb{R} \exists x \in \mathbb{R} (y = f(x) \Leftrightarrow (\forall z\in \mathbb{R} (y=f(z) \Rightarrow x=z)))$.
- 3) $\exists y \in \mathbb{R}, \forall x\in\mathbb{R} (y=f(x) \Leftrightarrow (\forall z\in\mathbb{R} (y=f(z)\Rightarrow (z=x))))$. Note: I'm starting off with an existential quantifier because the function's range does not have to be the set of real numbers (it can be a subset of the real numbers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

$1)$

$$(\exists n\in \Bbb N) \;\; : \;\; x=3^n$$

$2)$

$$(\forall y\in \Bbb R) \;\; (\exists \; ! \; x\in \Bbb R) \;\; : \;\; f(x)=y$$

Comment: What do you mean by invertible.

Comment: 2) What does $ \exists ! $ mean? It obviously can't mean that there doesn't exist such a thing. Also, $x = 3^n$ is a compound statement, so that is not allowed. You can only use simple statements and **no** exponentiation.

Comment: It means there exists One And Only One.

Comment: Sorry for my bad answer (+1)$.

Comment: It's okay tbh. Most of the questions I post require the use of axioms/basic mathematical principles. You're probably used to posting answers like the one above. I totally understand you. You didn't have to vote up my question, but thanks anyway. I voted up your answer in return.

Comment: Good night . it  is  too late  here . thanks.